# How to delete a deployment / image in kubernetes

Tags: image, azure, kubernetes, deployment, kubectl

I'm running kubernetes in azure.
I want to delete a specific deployment, with AZ AKS or kubectl.

The only info I've found is how to delete pods, but this is not what I'm looking for, since pods will regenerate once deleted.

I know I just can go to the ui and delete the deployment but i want to do it with az aks or kubectl.

[image]

I've run

```
kubectl get all -A
```

[image]

Then I copy the name of the deployment that I want to delete and run:

```
kubectl delete deployment zr-binanceloggercandlestick-btcusdt-2hour

kubectl delete deployment deployment.apps/zr-binanceloggercandlestick-btcusdt-12hour
```

but noting no success, i get these errors:

```
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "zr-binanceloggercandlestick-btcusdt-2hour" not found


error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form (e.g. 'C:\Users\amnesia\.azure-kubectl\kubectl.exe get resource/<resource_name>' instead of 'C:\Users\amnesia\.azure-kubectl\kubectl.exe get resource resource/<resource_name>'
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you're specifying the right namespace as Agrhya suggests.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Find out all deployments across all namespaces

```
kubectl get deploy -A
```

Then delete a deployment with deploymentname from namespace. deploymentname can be found from above command.

```
kubectl delete deploy deploymentname -n namespacename
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough#connect-to-the-cluster) on how to configure kubectl to connect to AKS.

Comment: But still lot of stuff like ingress etc are not deleted automatically, you need to delete that manually

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 11):

Use the below command.

> kubectl delete deployment deployment-name-here

More about the command [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#delete).

Comment: Maybe the default namespace is not set properly. Use the -n option to explicitly specify the namespace.